# Terrain shadow masking in Landsat 8 TOA image

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using hillShade function to mask the terrain shadow but its not give right output. hilshadow function also parameter azimuth angle and zenith angle is not define in Landsat * metadata.

Comment: Please provide more details about your question. A running code is always useful.

Comment: here is link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d1e91c4016a83344511319ad2f451d3f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have `SUN_AZIMUTH` and `SUN_ELEVATION` as part of the metadata. Something like this might work?

```
var azimuth = img.getNumber('SUN_AZIMUTH')
var zenith = ee.Number(90).subtract(img.getNumber('SUN_ELEVATION'))
var shaded_relief = ee.Terrain.hillShadow(elevation, azimuth, zenith)
Map.addLayer(shaded_relief)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5af9310372336840e924e729a2ec7d8d

Comment: Thanks Daniel its working....